# Code of built-in node.js modules

Tags: node.js, module, built-in

Where can I find source code of built-in node.js modules such as:

```
net, stream, path, sys etc.
```

As far as I know these are compiled into binaries that's why I can't find them in global modules directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the source in the GitHub Repo: https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib